# Change CD Rom drive letter Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

In Windows 2008 R2 how can I change CD Rom drive letter from e: to g: for example?

Comment: Voted to close. You ask an incredibly simple question that can be found on the web, yet you neglect to mention that you don't even see the drive to change the letter.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, RPS, pretend that none of us can actually see your computer from here. I know, mind-bending, but just try to pretend its true. The time to tell us that you've already tried stuff in the answers below but the drive isn't listed, is when you first ask the question, not after people have already spent time and energy trying to help you.

Comment: You should at least mark one of the answers as the correct answer!

Comment: Irony: question closed because instructions can be found on the web.  I search the web, and this is where I find instructions.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as off topic, sure looks like "relate to server administration".

Answer (score 8):

1. Richt-click "My Computer" and select "Manage"
2. Expand "Storage"
3. Select "Disk Management"
4. Right-click the drive and select "Change Driver Letter and Paths"

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it does not show up as removable storage cd rom.

Comment: @RPS Does it show up at all in Computer Management?

Comment: @Chris S, how should I know? Maybe the OS could be mistake it for being a thumb drive or something. I just find it strange if he can use the CD Rom if it does not show up in Computer Management.

Comment: Sorry! Looked at the wrong name, that was supposed to be at RPS.

Answer (score 0):

In Computer Management, go to Storage and right click on CDROM to change letter.

Comment: The problem is that it does not show up as removable storage cd rom.